# How to use generic type to a base class and interface both requiring the generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

### Intro

Consider an API with `PagedResults<T>` like so:

```
public class PagedResult<T> : PagedResultBase where T : class
{
    public IList<T> Results { get; set; }

    public PagedResult()
    {
        Results = new List<T>();
    }
}
```

`PagedResultBase` is simple, just has the page size and skip count properties.

Now, in addition, I have some `Result` classes that also contain `public IList<T> Results` but are not paged.

```
public class Response
{
    public List<AListDto> Results { get; set; }
}
```

### Desire

In my tests I'm hoping I can have them all implement an interface so I can make a generic base test class with some of the more basic tests. To this end, I added what I thought would work:

```
public interface IGetListResponse<T>
{
    IList<T> Results { get; set; }
}
```

### Non working (but preferred) change

I changed PagedResults to:

```
public class PagedResult<T> : PagedResultBase where T : class, IGetListResponse<T>
```

**Error**

But now the compiler [complains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0311) about the usage everywhere the PagedResultBase is inherited (?) from.

```
//Compiler error CS0311
//The type 'BListDto' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'PagedResult<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'BListDto' to 'IGetListResponse<T>'.
public class Response : PagedResult<BListDto>
```

### Working (but laborious) change

However, if I add the interface implementation definition to the inheritance location, the compiler seems fine with that.

```
//Base class no longer implements interface
public class PagedResult<T> : PagedResultBase where T : class

//Many locations in code would need to change to this
public class Response : PagedResult<BListDto>, IGetListResponse<BListDto> ...
public class Response : IGetListResponse<AListDto> ...
```

### Halp

To me this seems annoying, since the "T" definition is repeated to both the base class and the interface.

Is there a way to set up the `IGetListResponse` interface correctly using generics so that I can apply it only to the base paged class, and the (much fewer) non-paged responses directly?

**Minimal Code sample**

How can I change this code so it compiles? Without having to specify `BResponse : Interface` directly?

```
public class PagedResult<T> where T : class, IGetListResponse<T>
{
    public IList<T> Results { get; set; }

    public PagedResult()
    {
        Results = new List<T>();
    }
}

public class AResponse : IGetListResponse<Foo>
{
    public IList<Foo> Results { get; set; }
}

public interface IGetListResponse<T>
{
    IList<T> Results { get; set; }
}

public class BResponse : PagedResult<Foo>
{

}

public class Foo { }
```

Comment: If you just want to express the idea of "something that can produce a list of results on demand", a `Func<IList<T>>` is more flexible than an interface. You can implement this delegate multiple ways depending on the types involved. Alternatively, of course, there seems to be no good reason to use either an interface *or* a delegate, if your tests would just accept a `List<T>` directly. A single-property interface adds very little in the way of abstraction.

Comment: You can replace `T` by `IGetListResponse<T>` in the class `PagedResult`. Like `public IList<IGetListResponse<T>> Results { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it what you want to do ?

```
public class PagedResult<T> : IGetListResponse<T> where T : class
```

instead of your:

```
public class PagedResult<T> where T : class, IGetListResponse<T>
```

In your code PagedResult does not implement IGetListResponse<T>.

IGetListResponse<T> is a constraint on T generic type.

Comment: Wow... thank you, that totally works haha